# .NET Core Error using osascript to open new terminal in Mac

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

I am trying to open a new terminal and run a command from my console application, I found that in Mac the `CreateNoWindow` [is ignored](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24671) so instead I am using `osascript` to open the new terminal since `new` [is not working](https://scriptingosx.com/2020/03/macos-shell-command-to-create-a-new-terminal-window/) and `open` doesnt let me send a command.

When I run the code below I get the following error:

> hello ' : -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

> hello ' : -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
string test = $" -c \"osascript -e \' tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"echo hello\" \' \"";
test = new string(test.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(test);
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        UseShellExecute = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
        FileName = "/bin/bash",
        Arguments = test,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
    };
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

However, when I copy and paste the output from the console.writeline, the command works.
As you can See I already tried removing the control characters and still no luck.

I am not married to osascript, so if there is a better way of doing this I am also open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to escape the quotes again...:

```
string test = $" -c \"osascript -e \' tell application \\\"Terminal\\\" to do script \\\"echo hello\\\" \' \"";
```